# simple winapi spin control

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, wtl

I am trying to make a simple spin control and edit box in WTL &/ winapi. and this does not work properly, because I only see 0 as initial value and the arrows don t work, code here:

```
HWND spin = GetDlgItem(IDC_SPIN1);
HWND edit = GetDlgItem(IDC_RANDOM_EDIT);
::SendMessage(spin, UDM_SETBUDDY, (WPARAM)edit, 0); //set buddy
::SendMessage(spin, UDM_SETRANGE, MAKELPARAM(0,100), 0); //interval

::SendMessage(spin, UDM_SETBASE, 10, 0); //initial position
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your wparam and lparam reversed. You also have the low and high words reversed.

```
::SendMessage(spin, UDM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(100,0)); //interval
```

See the definitions of [`UDM_SETRANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`MAKELPARAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

In WTL you have wrapper class `CUpDownCtrl` for up-down control. So it goes as simple as this:

```
CUpDownCtrl Control = ... // e.g. GetDlgItem(IDC_MYCONTROL);
INT nMinValue = 0, nMaxValue = 100;
Control.SetRange(nMinValue, nMaxValue);
```